# How to change color dynamically on a circle programmatically

Tags: android, dynamic, colors, geometry

Update: Thx for the answers, problem solved. 
Yes code is missing, I am using Mapsforge library.

It had nothing to do with anything else than a bad comparison in a sqlite lookup 
which resulted no calling of toggleColor(). Now it works just fine!

Hi I am having trouble changing the color of a circle drawn on a canvas. The other color represents a different state of the circle.

It works fine with onTap i.e when I tap the circle on the screen, but when I try to do it programmatically like
circle.toggleColor() and then 
circle.requestRedraw() nothing happens.

How can I make this work programmatically?

```
@Override
public boolean onTap(LatLong geoPoint, Point viewPosition, Point tapPoint) {
        if (this.contains(viewPosition, tapPoint)) {
                toggleColor();
                this.requestRedraw();
                return true;
        }
        return false;
}
@Override


private void toggleColor() {
        if (this.getPaintFill().equals(LongPressAction.GREEN)) {
                this.setPaintFill(LongPressAction.RED);
        } else {
                this.setPaintFill(LongPressAction.GREEN);
        }
}
```

Comment: `requestRedraw` there is no such method in any class in the SDK

Comment: You should paste all code relevant to your question here.Otherwise it's hard to find the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx for answering

Yes code is missing in the snippet, I am using Mapsforge library.

It had nothing to do with anything else than a bad comparison in a sqlite lookup which resulted no calling of toggleColor(). Too much time spent on chasing that stupid mistake...

Now it works just fine!